# Cocos2d. My app crashes in -(void) update:(ccTime)delta method when I use a pre-existing NSMutableArray in a different method -(void)InitCats

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

guys! Sorry for my bad language.
My app crashes in Update method when I use array which I created in different method InitCats. I create NSMutableArray* Cats and CCSprite* CA in header file in @interface { }.

```
-(id)init
{
    [self InitCats];
    [self schedule:@selector(update:) interval:0.0f];
}

-(void)InitCats // This method is work well in -(id)init
{
    Cats = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:NumCats];

    for (int a=0; a<NumCats; a++)
    {
        CCSprite* Cat=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1.png"];
        [Cats addObject:Cat];
    }

}

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
for (int a=0; a<NumCats; a++)
    {
        CA = [Cats objectAtIndex:a]; //In this place I have ERROR, app crashes
        CA.position = CGPointMake(CA.position.x-1, CA.position.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: 0123456789012345     ARC ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you pointing to released object. try initialize your array

```
Cats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:NumCats];
```

and on dealloc

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [Cats release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue is this statement:

```
Cats = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:NumCats];
```

Which will create an auto-released object, however the pointer to this object will be non-`nil` after it's auto-released, and hence your code is referencing a deallocated object.

You already have a fix:

```
Cats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:NumCats];
```

and **remove the `arrayWithCapacity` call from within the `InitCats` method**.

(note your capitalization of method and instance variable names is unconventional).